# Criar uma tabela de calculo de frete no sql server 2012

Tags: sql

Estou com a seguinte questão e preciso da ajuda dos especialista, para poder dar sequencia no meu projeto. Preciso criar uma tabela de frete igual da imagem abaixo, só que não sei se crio uma tabela unica ou crio varias tabelas, porque depois tenho que fazer um join com minha tabela de pedidos para calcular o frete.

segue a imagem da tabela que preciso criar no sql, esta tabela tem valor por peso, estado e cidade(se e capital ou interior)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue a forma que criei as tabelas, agora me surgiu uma duvida, como vou tratar o calculo do peso com e estrutura de tabelas abaixo que criei, criei uma tabela de estado, uma tabela de tarifas pra verificar se e capital ou interior, e a tabela de preços e como agora verificar o peso também esta e minha duvida.
dede já agradeço.

```
CREATE TABLE Estados
(
  Id INT,
  Sigla VARCHAR(2),
  CONSTRAINT PK_Estados PRIMARY KEY (Id, Sigla)
)

CREATE TABLE Tarifas
(
  Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
  Descricao VARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE TabelaPreco
(
  Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
  IdEstado INT,
  IdTarifa INT,
  Preco1 decimal default 0, --Faixa 5
  Preco2 decimal default 0, --Faixa 10
  Preco3 decimal default 0, --Faixa 15
  Preco4 decimal default 0, --Faixa 20
  Preco5 decimal default 0, --Faixa 30
  Preco6 decimal default 0, --Faixa 50
  Preco7 decimal default 0, --Faixa 75
  Preco8 decimal default 0, --Faixa 100
  PrecoAdicionalKG decimal default 0 --Preco Adional KG
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--sem se ater a PKs e FKs

```
CREATE TABLE Estados
(
  Id INT,
  Sigla VARCHAR(2),
  CONSTRAINT PK_Estados PRIMARY KEY (Id, Sigla)
)

CREATE TABLE Tarifas
(
  Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
  Descricao VARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE Faixas
(
  Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
  Descricao VARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE TabelaPreco
(
  Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
  IdEstado INT,
  IdTarifa INT,
  IdFaixa INT,
  VigenciaDe DATE,
  VigenciaAte DATE,
  Preco  decimal default 0
  PrecoAdicionalKG decimal default 0 --Preco Adional KG
)
```

Creio que falta também definir onde a informação "destino" fica , ela
altera o valor do frete ?

Comment: Motta bom dia, só uma duvida, na tabela de faixa e pra colocar o peso correto, se e 5, 10, 20...etc e isso mesmo?

Comment: Sim , pois vai que a regra mude , algo como apareça uma faixa de "150" , a aplicação teria de ser alterada , assim basta criar um registro.